# Android Actionbar Menu Item not Selecting

Tags: android

I have an android Activity with a bottom menu navigation bar, That navigates between three fragments and a single top menu item that should open a new activity, But the top menu ActionBar item is not responding to click events. Maybe there is something am missing? Or should I be handling the menu from within my fragments?

**Here is  my code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set Network Connection Listener
    setConnectionListener(this);

    //check the network connectivity when activity is created
    checkConnection();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, HomeFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();

    // Used to select item programmatically
    // bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top, menu);
    // return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Menu Clicked " + item.getItemId());
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.tab_cart:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My Menu top.xml res menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.shopcentra.activities.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/tab_cart"
    android:icon="@mipmap/cart"
    android:title="@string/cart"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/notification_layout"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: are you getting  Menu Clicked log in your Logcat

Comment: @VinayakB No I am not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where you've added a View.OnClickListener on the "tab_cart". If you have set one, please share that code as well otherwise, add an OnCLickListener on that view and see if the problem persists then as well.
**EDIT**: code to add OnClickListener on menu item:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem tabCartMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.tab_cart);
    View notificationActionView = menuItem.getActionView();
    notificationActionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onOptionsItemSelected(tabCartMenuItem));
        }
    });
}
```

Try adding this code to your onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

Comment: I did not set an `OnClickListener` on `tab_cart` which is the id for the menu item, so how do I set `OnClickListener` for a menu item

Comment: Happy to help :)